# Routing Error when running controller spec (rspec)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rspec

I feel like I have everything I need in my routes.rb, my controller, and my controller spec, but for some reason I'm still getting a routing error (ActionController::RoutingError). Here's my controller:

```
class HunchController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  def results
    auth_token_key = params[:auth_token_key]
    user_id = params[:user_id]
    @user = User.create!
    @user.auth_token = @user.get_auth_token(auth_token_key, user_id)
    @recommended_books = @user.get_recommended_books(@user.auth_token)
  end
end
```

Here's my controller spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe HunchController do
  describe "POST 'results'" do
    before do
      @params = {
        :auth_token_key => "my auth token",
        :user_id => "my user id"
      }
    end

    it "succeeds" do
      post :results, @params
      response.should be_success
    end
  end
end
```

And here's my routes.rb:

```
MyApplicationName::Application.routes.draw do
  root :to => 'hunch#index'

  resources :users
  post 'hunch/results' => "hunch#results"
  match '/results' => 'hunch#results'
end
```

---

EDIT: Here's my rake routes output:

```
         root        /                         {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"index"}
hunch_results POST   /hunch/results(.:format)  {:controller=>"hunch", :action=>"results"}
      results        /results(.:format)        {:controller=>"hunch", :action=>"results"}
        users GET    /users(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"users"}
              POST   /users(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"users"}
     new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"users"}
    edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users"}
         user GET    /users/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}
              PUT    /users/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"users"}
```

---

EDIT #2: I'm getting this error with my users#show test too. Here's the actual error:

```
  1) UsersController#show succeeds
     Failure/Error: get :show
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches {:controller=>"users", :action=>"show"}
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:13:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: Please add your rake routes output.

Comment: What's the actual routing error?

Comment: Given that routing error you've posted the wrong spec. The error is in the `UsersController` spec, not the `HunchController` spec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got the same problem when gem journey was updated to the latest version. And find that if you got a route like this:

```ruby
user GET    /users/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}
```

which have a param (id in this case), you **necessarily need** to render a link in template or use a user_path/user_url variables in controller **with param too**, so in your templates try to find:

```ruby
<%= link_to "linkname", user_path %>
```

and replace by

```ruby
<%= link_to "linkname", user_path(@user) %>
```

or search in any controller for the `user_path`/`user_url` usage and replace them by `user_path(@user)`/`user_url(@user)` accordingly.